# Hessian matrix (2x2) has trace,det=0 but a negative eigenvalue--is this matrix PSD?

Tags: matrices, convex-analysis, positive-semidefinite, hessian-matrix

I'm trying to show whether the function $f(x)=sin(\frac{\pi x_2} {2})$ is convex for $x\in \mathbb{R}^2$, where $0<x_1\le2$ and $0<x_2\le1$

When I compute the Hessian, I find $$H=\nabla^2f=\begin{matrix} 0 & 0\\ 0 &-(\frac{\pi}{2})^2 sin(\frac{\pi x_2}{2})\end{matrix}$$

This matrix has $Trace(H) = 0 $and $det(H) = 0$, which suggests to me that this matrix is positive semidefinite. However, this matrix has a negative eigenvalue and does not satisfy $v^THv\ge0$, which implies that the matrix is not PSD.

How can I rectify this? Is this matrix PSD or no?
Thank you!

Comment: you should prove to yourself that a symmetric positive semidefinite matrix has trace zero **iff** it is the zero matrix

Comment: How is the trace equal to zero when the lower-right element is negative over the entire interval? At any rate, neither eigenvalue is ever positive, so how can $H$ be PSD?

Comment: *"This matrix has $Trace(H) = 0 $and $det(H) = 0$, which suggests to me that this matrix is positive semidefinite."* Why??? And the trace of your $H$ isn't zero, because $x_2$ is not an even number.